# Face-recognition using Opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, face-recognition

I need to do a face recognition system using opencv [LBP and here is the link where the facerec code](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html#local-binary-patterns-histograms-in-opencv).

In this code the CSV file has to be generated for Multiple users and the code will recognize if the input face is in the list of CSV not.

My intention is to do face verification against single user. i.e., User will register his face for the first time ( I will write it in csv ) and whenever the same user tries to authenticate 
I will collect the few images of the user and compare with the previous CSV file. How to do this with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

consider a threshold (given by predict function) smaller than a value to determine if the face in known or not.
for the first time, passing face will be predicted as unknown (smaller than the threshold), then put it in the DB (csv file too). for the next pass, it should predict by a value a bit greater than the previous, you can take it , and so on until you think that the the prediction is ok for you